# xboard chess gui doesn't send second user move

Tags: c++, unix, protocols, chess

I am trying to make a chess engine for xboard. After the first move made by user, my chess engine replies, and then xboard doesn't send the next move made by the user.

I recorded whatever xboard sends to my engine. Here's a code sample where my engine replies `e2e4` with `move e7e6`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

std::ofstream f("xboardtoeng.txt");
std::ofstream f2("engtoxboard.txt");

int main(int argc, char** argv){  

    while (true){
        std::string s;
        std::cin>>s;
        f<<s<<std::endl;
        if (s=="protover"){
            std::cout<<"feature done=1"<<std::endl;
            f2<<"feature done=1"<<std::endl;
        }else if (s=="e2e4"){
            usleep(100000);
            std::cout<<"move e7e6"<<std::endl;
            f2<<"move e7e6"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

After compiling, I ran `xboard -fcp $PWD/a.out`. Then, I made e2e4 move as user in the GUI. After my engine gives its reply, I made another move (say, e4e5). Here's what I got in `xboardtoeng.txt`:

```
xboard
protover 2
accepted usermove
accepted myname
accepted done
new
random
level 40 5 0
post
hard
time 30000
otim 30000
usermove e2e4
```

Here, xboard did send the first move to my engine. However, the next user move isn't sent. Any idea where I did wrong?

I use xboard version 4.8.0

Comment: xboard assumed the other side was a computer engine. It was waiting for your engine to make a move. Did your engine make a reply?

Comment: here's what happened: After xboard sent "e2e4" to my engine, my engine replied "move e7e6". xboard received my engine's reply and displayed it on the board. After that, I tried (as the user) making another move on the gui, but the move was never transmitted to my engine. Shouldn't the engine be the one expecting a message from xboard at this state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, it is because Xboard send SIGINT and SIGTERM signal. Adding code `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)` solve my problem.

[source 1](http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=51115)
[source 2](http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/engine-intf.html#7)